# How to construct a loop that runs three times and tests the age input

Tags: c#, windows

I need to make a loop that runs for 3 times and a switch for three age groups `0-10`  `11-20` and `21-65` with the following code:

```
class Program
    {
        private static object N;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string answer;                                   
            {
              Console.WriteLine("please enter your name:");
              string name = Console.ReadLine();

              Console.WriteLine("please enter your surname:");
              string surname = Console.ReadLine();

              Console.WriteLine("please enter your age:");
              string age = Console.ReadLine();        

              Console.WriteLine("please enter your adress:");
              string adress = Console.ReadLine();

              Console.WriteLine("hallo,{0} {1},veel sucess met C#", name, surname);

              Console.WriteLine("zijn deze gegevens juist? J/N");
              answer = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while(answer == "N");
        }
   }
```

I tried some things to test the age, but I always got errors. Also, I don't know how to write the loop code correctly.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction for both problems?

Sorry for my bad English I'm Dutch.

*NOTE: the OP mentioned under one of the answers that this is not a homework assignment.*

Comment: try some books for novice c# programmers

Comment: Looks like homework assignment. If your question is about homework, you can ask, but make sure you don't ask others to write the code for you.

Comment: your code will not compile! you forgot do keyword. If you want to do this loop exacly 3 times use FOR loop

Comment: @Jacek: his code will compile. However, the while-loop will go only over the empty statement (and as such, will either break or loop forever). The asker probably want do-while like you say though.

Comment: `string age = (Console.ReadLine());` should be `int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: @user1758580 Have you gotten it working?

Comment: I understand you are new at SO. You changed to question to contain the answer. I will roll that back, as the original answer is what the thread is about. It is ok to edit questions and answers, but don't change it completely, as that makes the whole Q and A unintelligible for later visitors ;). Questions on an answer can go under the answer, which is where you already asked it and where it was already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch statements operate on specific values, not ranges, so you'd want to use a series `if` statements instead.

Use a counter (declared outside of the loop and incremented on every execution) to determine how many times the loop has run (or use a `for` loop).

**Edit**

```
class Program
{
    private static object N;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string answer;
        int runCount= 0;

        do
        {
          ++runCount;
          Console.WriteLine("please enter your name:");
          string name = Console.ReadLine();

          Console.WriteLine("please enter your surname:");
          string surname = Console.ReadLine();

          Console.WriteLine("please enter your age:");
          int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

          if(age >= 0 && age <= 10)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Child");
          }
          else if(age <= 20)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Young adult");
          }
          else if(age <= 65)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Adult");
          }

          Console.WriteLine("please enter your adress:");
          string adress = Console.ReadLine();

          Console.WriteLine("hallo,{0} {1},veel sucess met C#", name, surname);

          Console.WriteLine("zijn deze gegevens juist? J/N");
          answer = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        while(runCount < 3 && answer == "N");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice full working example. But on SO, we'd rather not do the work for homework assignments, instead try to point in the right direction (I know, moral police ;) ). Anyway, +1. (PS: `string age` should probably be `int age`).

Comment: @Abel I can take it back out if you like. I had the same reservation, hence not posting it initially.

Comment: problem now is that i have put in the canges you have made but visual studio wil give Error 3 Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int' i dont know what the hell it means and so to speak for the moral police mineded pepole i am making this on my own for my self not as an homework assignments

Comment: @user1758580 it's great that you're doing this to learn. As Abel pointed out, I accidentally left in `string age = int.Parse(...` where it should be `int age = int.Parse(...`. Also, please refrain from using words like "hell" we're all just here to help, no reason to get upset.

Comment: oh sorry but the opperator thing wont go away its not just one error line its al the lines where the <=

Comment: The line above the first `if` statement reads exactly like this: `int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`?

Comment: it stops with compile erros for age case operators <=

Comment: Could you post the full code you're having trouble with in your question please? It'll be easier to see what's wrong that way

Comment: @user1758580 I just copied and pasted the code into Visual Studio and it compiles. Maybe try copying it as it is and pasting it directly to see if that helps.

Comment: i did that to now it complies but the last thing is i want it to loop over for the next person When answer is J and begin all over for the fist if the answer is N

Comment: Change `while(runCount < 3 && answer == "N");` to `while(runCount < 3 && answer == "J");`

Comment: program just shuts down when you give answer J or N

Comment: The program will shut down for any value that is not `while(runCount < 3 && answer == "J");` whatever string is provided there, in this case `J` or when `runCount` is equal to, or greater than `3`. The string comparison is case sensitive, if you need it not to be, try using `while(runCount < 3 && "J".Equals(answer, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));`

Comment: only thing i want is that it give the input of al 3 loops at the end of the last persons good input

Comment: I think now is a good time to choose an answer to this question, look in to storing the results of each iteration through the loop in a `class` or a `struct` and adding it to a `List` or something else from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. I'd suggest opening a new question regarding any open issues, that way you'll get more responses.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like the following:

```
var ageGroups = new [] { "0-10",  "11-20", "21-65"};

foreach(var ageGroup in ageGroups)
{
    // do your thing. This will loop three times, once for each age group
    // example of switch (but: code-smell, you probably want class hierarchy later)
    switch(ageGroup)
    {
        case "0-10":
         // do somethihg
         break;
    }
}
```

Or, as MrFox says, when you don't have predefined age groups (but I don't see that in your question) then:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    // do your thing
    // example of if-statement for range (cannot do with switch):
    int convertedAge;
    if(int.TryParse(age, out convertedAge))
    {
        if(convertedAge >= 0 && convertedAge <= 10)
        {
             // do your thing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the age will be a value someone entered, if for example they enter 5, it will not match to "0-10".

Comment: ok the age group var works but i made an error in the question its need to get the age form the dtring age and then shown with an read line you are and child adult or senior based on the case swith i was making but when i had it i constandly got errors so that didnt work as i wanted and now im stuck

Comment: @user1758580: I anticipated that question (because of MrFox), see my example. You should be fine to continue from there. Or show what you have and we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface is multi-lingual some texts towards the user are written in English, others in dutch, make up your mind or allow the user to choose his language.

As for programming skills, you should google general C# constructs. Also this [course](http://www.nand2tetris.org/) is very good. Last as a programmer you better learn English, no matter what country you come from.

```
class Program
{
    static int age;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string answer;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter your name:");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("please enter your surname:");
            string surname = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("please enter your age:");
            age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("please enter your adress:");
            string adress = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("hallo,{0} {1},veel sucess met C#", name, surname);

            Console.WriteLine("zijn deze gegevens juist? J/N");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        while (answer == "N");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (age >= 0 && age <= 10)
            {
                // First age group.
            }
            if (age >= 11 && age <= 20)
            {
                // Second age group.
            }
            if (age >= 21 && age <= 65)
            {
                // Third age group.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: thanks there is now a do to make the while loop correct. It's unclear to me where the for-loop should go.

Comment: Note that this code still has the wrong while-loop, which either runs forever or breaks immediately. Also, why do you need a for-loop when all you do is test an already set variable? The for-loop is redundant ;). I figured the for-loop should go around the whole block of code.

Comment: yes i took it over in a new project along side my own to check the difernces.

i changed the thins i dident have but it stops with operators in the age cases